# Traverse a file & read content to save to csv

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, os.walk

I have directory structure like :

```
`~/ansible-environments/aws/random_name_1/inventory/group_vars/all`
~/ansible-environments/aws/random_name_2/inventory/group_vars/all`
~/ansible-environments/aws/random_name_3/inventory/group_vars/all`
```

the all file looks like

```
`
alias: bloodyhell
vendor_id: 42
isv_secret_key: "{{ vendor_id }}-SecretKey"
isv_secret_key_id: "{{ vendor_id }}-SecretKeyId"
products: rms_scl
LMIT: 80
sales_order_no: 'RMS_BSO_8182'
`
```

I need to write a python script that can traverse this directory struct and then extract **alias,LMIT,products** and write the content in a csv file as:

```
alias,LMIT,products
bloodyhell,80,rms_scl
.

.
.
so on
.
```
I wrote a code as follows:

```
import os
import sys
rootdir='/home/ubuntu/ansible-environments/aws'
#print "aa"
for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
#  print "a"
  for j in subdirs:
       try:
           mypath = rootdir + '/' + j + '/' + 'inventory/group_vars/all'
           print  mypath
           fo = open(mypath, 'r')
           f = fo.readlines()
           #    print f
           for line in f:
               # print line
               if ('isv_alias' in line or 'LMID' in line or 'products' in line):
                   path = rootdir + '/' + 'list.csv'
                   fi = open(path, 'a')
                   fi.write(line)
                   fi.close()
           fo.close()
       except:
           pass
```

This is the result i am getting:

`` `isv_alias: "bloodhell"^M
isv_alias: bloodhell
products: rms_scl
LMID: 80
isv_alias: rmstest2
products: rms_scl
LMID: 80
isv_alias: suricatatest
products: rms_ems_hosted
LMID: 26 ``

Can someone help me fix it up ?